# Use button to control iframe width

Tags: javascript

There are three buttons with each `iframe`. I wanna adjust the `iframe` width when the user clicks the button. I got a solution from an expert if there are two buttons as below:

```
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  const wasChange = e.target.matches(':first-child');
  const iframe = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  iframe.style.width = wasChange ? "60%" : '100%';

});
```

He told me that for three buttons solution: Use an array of styles instead, and look up the index of the clicked button in the array. `const styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%']` and `const index = [...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)` to find the style to apply, and Once you have the index, just look up the value in the array and assign to the `style.frame.style.width = styles[index];`

I don't understand what he means, can anyone help me here? Below is the code:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  const wasChange = e.target.matches(':first-child'); 
  const iframe = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  iframe.style.width = wasChange ? "60%" : '100%';
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe01"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe02"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe03"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe04"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
      </div>
      <p>Iframe Container 01</div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe01"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div >
      <div>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
      </div>
      <p>Iframe Container 02</div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe02"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
      </div>
      <p>Iframe Container 03</div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe03"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
        <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
      </div>
      <p>Iframe Container 4</div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe04"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for only two state but you have a three buttons so you can not use `wasChange ? "60%" : '100%'` because the condition covers only two states.

So you can define an array with three numbers for styles `styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%']` (which means `90px` for first button, `60%` for second button and so on) and then find the corresponding index with `[...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)` and use them with `iframe.style.width = styles[index]`.

```js
const styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%']

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  const iframe = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  
  var index = [...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)
  //console.log('(index: value)',index,styles[index]);
  iframe.style.width = styles[index];
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe01"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe02"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe03"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button>Small</button>
      <button>Medium</button>
      <button>Big</button>
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframe04"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**
First the HTML structure is not correct, anyway I correct it.

To find out button use `var button = e.target.closest("button")` and don't forgot you have to set class for root of `iframe` and then do like this to find out `iframe`: `button.closest('.containFrame').querySelector("iframe")`

```js
const styles = ['90px', '60%', '100%']

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var button = e.target.closest("button");
  if (!button) return;
  const iframe =     button.closest('.containFrame').querySelector("iframe");
  
  var index = [...button.parentElement.children].indexOf(button)
  //console.log('(index: value)',index,styles[index]);
  iframe.style.width = styles[index];
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

#iframe01 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#iframe02 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#iframe03 {
  background-color: green;
}

#iframe04 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

        <div class="containFrame">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
                </div>
                <p>Iframe Container 01
            </div>
            <iframe id="iframe01"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="containFrame">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
                </div>
                <p>Iframe Container 02
            </div>
            <iframe id="iframe02"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="containFrame">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
                </div>
                <p>Iframe Container 03
            </div>
            <iframe id="iframe03"></iframe>
        </div>

        <div class="containFrame">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Small</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Medium</span></button>
                    <button><span class="buttonStyle">Large</span></button>
                </div>
                <p>Iframe Container 4
            </div>
            <iframe id="iframe04"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This looks great, but every time when I click the button, there are something appearing in the console, is that normal?

Comment: No I  show the text for your understanding. I remove it now. Please check it again

Comment: Hi, the script works for this structure of HTML, but if I add more div then it can't target the right iframe...And If I add span inside the button tag then it won't work as well...Any solution to these two questions? Maybe use querySelector?

Comment: Where do you want to add more div? please show the html

Comment: I've added an updated snippet below the original one, where there is one more level div, and added span inside the button. I guess it's not convenient if I add more div level to the container since the script is using `var index = [...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)`, I was thinking using querySelector to target the iframe instead maybe?

Comment: I updated my answer. you can use `closest` and `querySelector `

Comment: My code editor suggests that: Forgotten 'debugger' statement? Missing semicolon. I can ignore it right?

Comment: Thanks. I removed the debugger. Is it OK?